# How to test a Ruby Roda app using RSpec to pass an argument to app.new with initialize

Tags: ruby, rspec, rack, roda

This question probably has a simple answer but I can't find any examples for using Roda with RSpec3, so it is difficult to troubleshoot.

I am using Marston and Dees "Effective Testing w/ RSpec3" book which uses Sinatra instead of Roda. I am having difficulty passing an object to `API.new`, and, from the book, this is what works with Sinatra but fails with a "wrong number of arguments" error when I substitute Roda.

Depending on whether I pass arguments with `super` or no arguments with `super()`, the error switches to indicate that the failure occurs either at the initialize method or in the call to Rack::Test::Methods post in the spec.

I see that in Rack::Test, in the Github repo README, I may have to use `Rack::Builder.parse_file("config.ru")` but that didn't help.

Here are the two errors that rspec shows when using `super` without brackets:

Failures:

```
  1) MbrTrak::API POST /users when the user is successfully recorded returns the user id
     Failure/Error: post '/users', JSON.generate(user)
     
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
     # ./spec/unit/app/api_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in <module:MbrTrak>'
```

And when using `super()`:

```
  1) MbrTrak::API POST /users when the user is successfully recorded returns the user id
     Failure/Error: super()
     
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
     # ./app/api.rb:8:in `initialize'
     # ./spec/unit/app/api_spec.rb:10:in `new'
     # ./spec/unit/app/api_spec.rb:10:in `app'
     # ./spec/unit/app/api_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in <module:MbrTrak>'
```

This is my api_spec.rb:

```
require_relative '../../../app/api'
require 'rack/test'

module MbrTrak
  RecordResult = Struct.new(:success?, :expense_id, :error_message)
  
  RSpec.describe API do
    include Rack::Test::Methods
    def app
      API.new(directory: directory)
    end
    let(:directory) { instance_double('MbrTrak::Directory')}
    
    describe 'POST /users' do
      context 'when the user is successfully recorded' do
        it 'returns the user id' do
          user = { 'some' => 'user' }
          allow(directory).to receive(:record)
            .with(user)
            .and_return(RecordResult.new(true, 417, nil))
          post '/users', JSON.generate(user)
          parsed = JSON.parse(last_response.body)
          expect(parsed).to include('user_id' => 417)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my api.rb file:

```
require 'roda'
require 'json'

module MbrTrak
  class API < Roda
    def initialize(directory: Directory.new)
      @directory = directory
      super()
    end
    plugin :render, escape: true
    plugin :json
    route do |r|
      r.on "users" do
        r.is Integer do |id|
          r.get do
            JSON.generate([])
          end
        end
        r.post do
          user = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
          result = @directory.record(user)
          JSON.generate('user_id' => result.user_id)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My config.ru is:

```
require "./app/api"

run MbrTrak::API
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. Please take the time to use proper formatting as it helps others understand your question. "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" will help.

Answer (score 0):

Well roda has defined initialize method that receives env as an argument which is being called by the app method of the class. Looks atm like this

```
def self.app
   ...
   lambda{|env| new(env)._roda_handle_main_route}
   ...
end
```

And the constructor of the app looks like this

```
def initialize(env)
```

When you run your `config.ru` with `run MbrTrack::API` you are actually invoking the `call` method of the roda class which looks like this

```
def self.call(env)
  app.call(env)
end
```

Because you have redefined the constructor to accept hash positional argument this no longer works and it throws the error you are receiving

```
ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

Now what problem are you trying to solve, if you want to make your API class configurable one way to go is to try out [dry-configurable](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-configurable/0.14/) which is part of the great `dry-ruby` gem collection.

If you want to do something else feel free to ask.

It has been a long time since you posted your question so hope you will still find this helpful.